# Is there any new XmlConverter to use with retrofit in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit

Today i encountered this question [What kind of XmlConverter can I use for Retrofit in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774071/what-kind-of-xmlconverter-can-i-use-for-retrofit-in-android)
When looking for a problem i'm having, and i wondered if there are any new xml conversion library that i can use with retrofit in android.
As it is an old question ( four years ago ) it might have a new answer nowadays!